# Javascript - Unable to access module variable from script tag

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Hi all i am new to javascript.

i write the following code paths.js

```
import { App } from './App.js';
import { Helper } from './helper.js';

var tempVar = new class {
  constructor() {
    this.App = new App();
    this.helper = new Helper(this);
  }
}
```

App.js

```
export class App {
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Helper.js

```
export class Helper {
  constructor(paths) {

  }
}
```

import the above code inside the index.html file like this

```
<script type="module" src="paths.js"></script>
```

now i need to access tempVar from another script tag

```
<script>
  console.log(tempVar);
</script>
```

How to do this. or i am doing anything wrong or misunderstand the code.

I received the error like tempVar is not defined.

Comment: What are the exceptions you are getting? And what is the content of `App.js` and `helper.js`?

Comment: @Titulum question updated

Comment: Put shortly: you cannot access variables defined in type=module script from another inline script. If you want to debug something, you can attach the `tempVar` to a `window` like this: `window.tempVar = new class {...}` and then access it like this: `console.log(window.tempVar);`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in order to use modules you will have to serve your files with an http server. You can easily do so by adding this small `server.js` in your folder:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('.'));
app.listen(8080);
```

First, install the `express` package by running `npm install express`, then start up the server by running `node server.js`.

Then, you can request your html file by navigating to `http://localhost:8080`. Then, you will get the following error:

> ReferenceError: tempVar is not defined

This is because your `module` gets loaded *after* your inline script. To change this behavior, add all your javascript logic in `paths.js`. If you change it like this:

```js
import { App } from './modules/App.js';
import { Helper } from './modules/helper.js';

var tempVar = new class {
  constructor() {
    this.App = new App();
    this.helper = new Helper(this);
  }
}

console.log(tempVar);
```

it should correctly print the contents of `tempVar`!

Answer (score 0):

```
class App  {
    constructor(){
        document.write('Hello! programmer?<br />');
    }
}

class Helper{
    constructor(paths){
        document.write('Hello! Coder?<br />');
    }
}
let Paths = new class  {

    constructor(){
        this.App = new App();
        this.Helper = new Helper(this);
    }
}

//index.html

    <!DOCTYPE html >
    <html charset='utf-8'>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="paths.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          let Path = new Paths();
          //console.log(Path);

        </script>

      </body>
    </html>

//NOTE:

You may also refer to the following link to learn on how to declare or use classes in es6  [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes][1]


  [1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes
```